# ASP.NET Web api get parameters

Tags: asp.net, api

I have an API built with asp.net with 2 endpoints.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAllFoodProducts()

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFoodByCategory([FromQuery]string category)
```

But when I call: `Food?category=asfasf` I get this: `The request matched multiple endpoints`.

I know I can change the `[HttpGet] to [HttpGet("{category}")]` but then I cannot call the API with `Food?category=asfasf`, only with `Food/asfasf`. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the route for `GetFoodByCategory`. For example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetFood")]
public IActionResult GetFoodByCategory([FromQuery]string category)
```

and then you can call it like this,

```
/Food/GetFood?category=asfasf
```